# Fetch multiple join result with several condition in a single model query codeigniter with pagination

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

This is my model function which is working. I have to find out counts of some fields. (eg. I have to find the count of requirementid from rfq table). Can I write several queries in one function and dispaly with pagination?

Any help would be appreciated

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
         $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
          $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
           $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
           $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
        $query =  $this->db->get();  
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                 $data[] = $row;
            }
           return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->query()` to write your queries. For example see below code.

```
$SQL="Your custome query";
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
$result= $query->result_array();
```

Comment: i want more than one query result in a single function